# Ajax request : get text from database and display in div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, phpmyadmin

My goal is to perform an AJAX request when clicking on a button to retrieve "name" and "story" stored in my database. Each button will get info of another hero.
I'm working on multiple files.

With my current code (which is the closer to what seems to be correct in my mind) the **switchHeroInfo** will always change the text to "*TestName*" and "*StoryName*" instead of "*Gertrude*" "*An old lady*"(stored in database).

Can you enlight me on what may be the cause of my struggles?

the php file for connecting to database : **connect_database.php**

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=biomass;charset=utf8', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
}
catch(Exception $e)
{

    die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

The Javascript part :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".hero_portrait").click(function()
    {
        var index = $(this).data("id");

        $.ajax(
        {
           type: "POST",
           url: "../php/get_data.php",
           data: {newIndex:index},
           success: function(data)
            {
            // Display  {"nick":"Gertrude","0":"Gertrude","story":"Vieille folle senile","1":"Vieille folle senile"}
               alert(data);

            //Display : undefined
               alert(data.story);
                $("#hero_name").html(data.nick);
                $("#hero_story").html(data.story);
            },
            error: function() 
            { 
                alert("Request failure"); 
            }    
        });
    });
});
```

The php file : **get_data.php**

```
<?php
$tempValue = $_POST['newIndex'];
$sql = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE ID = :indexValue');
$sql->bindParam(":indexValue", $tempValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();

while($data = $sql->fetch())
{       
    ?>
    <script>
        $heroNameTemp = <?php echo json_encode($data["name"]); ?>;
        $heroStoryTemp = <?php echo json_encode($data["story"]); ?>;
    </script>

    <?php
}
$sql->closeCursor();
?>
```

Finally the HTML relative to the current problem:

```
<div id="squad_portraits">
            <div class="hero_portrait" id="1"></div>
            <div class="hero_portrait" id="2"></div>
            <div class="hero_portrait" id="3"></div>
            <div class="hero_portrait" id="4"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="hero_info">
            <h2 id="hero_name">Hero_Name</h2>
            <p id="hero_story"> Hero_Description</p>
        </div>
```

If i switch my sql request :

```
$tempValue = $_POST['newIndex'];
$sql = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE ID = :indexValue');
```

to this

```
$tempValue = 4;
$sql = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE ID = 4');
```

AND add the following to my HTML file

```
<?php include("../php/get_data.php"); ?>
```

everything works but my index will always be "4".

Comment: You should not be using the attribute `id` to hold data. The `id` is for holding the name of that field for use with javascript and addressing that field in the DOMDocument

Comment: putting script tags (and javascript) in get_data.php is a completely wrong aproach. get_data.php should _only_ echo a json string (or any other string that can be parsed/interpreted by javascript)

Comment: Use the [data attribute instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues and missunderstandings in your code.

first, in ajax change data to this:

```
data: {newIndex:index},   // remove the (), simple syntax misstake
```

This should solve the sql problem.

Now the get_data.php:

```
<?php
// including db connection is missing here for $bdd

// You should add a test here, wether you've received any and correct data in 'newIndex'
if(empty($_POST['newIndex']) {
    // throw an error, send that back to ajax (with a fitting http response code) and exit script
    http_response_code(400);
    $error = new stdClass();
    $error->msg = "Parameter newIndex was missing";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');  // tell the browser that there is some json coming!
    echo json_encode($error);
    exit;
}
$tempValue = $_POST['newIndex'];

                     // only select the values you need (name, story)
$sql = $bdd->prepare('SELECT name, story FROM heroes WHERE ID = :indexValue');
$sql->bindParam(":indexValue", $tempValue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sql->execute();

$data = $sql->fetch(); // if you only expect/need one row, no while is needed
// echo ONE json string as plain string:
header('Content-Type: application/json');  // tell the browser that there is some json coming!
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now you receive content of `$data` as a json as param (`data`) in the success-callback of your ajax, which you can use like this:

```
success: function(data){
   $("#hero_name").html(data.name);
   $("#hero_story").html(data.story);
}
```

*Finally* let's change storing the item's id from the id attribute to the data-attribute:

In html:

```
 <div class="hero_portrait" data-id="1"></div>
 <div class="hero_portrait" data-id="2"></div>
```

and in javascript change

```
 var index = $(this).attr("id");
```

to

```
 var index = $(this).data("id");  // $(this).attr("data-id"); will also work
```

Comment: i must admit i'm completely clueless about the  correct way of handling **if(empty($_POST['newIndex']))** error return.

Comment: I added an alert(data) into the success function (which return :  {"nick":"Gertrude","0":"Gertrude","story":"Vieille folle senile","1":"Vieille folle senile"}... name and story does change when clicking another button.         i changed "name" to "nick" everywhere

Comment: is  $sql->closeCursor(); at the end of get_data.php still necessary? i updated the code get-data.php like you did in your exemple but an alert(data.nick);  into the ajax success function display "undefined".

Comment: closeCursor is not necessary, because you exit the script anyway, so all connections will be closed.

Comment: have you also changed the sql Select from "name" to "nick"?

Comment: thanks for the update.  I did modified each name reference.  The last part i dont get is storing those data.wathever into my div.     i'm adding my new update to the ajax part for more clarity

Comment: now your js doesn't recognise/parse the json string as json. Two possible fixes: add ContentType header in php (anywhere before an echo):  `header('Content-Type: application/json');`, _OR_ (not so good) parse data in ajax-success like this: `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: I can't thank you enough after those days of headache! the result is perfect.   You talk about several issues and misunderstanding, i spent lots of hours facing video/ text tutorial + trial and error just for this problem had caused lot of confusion in my mind mixing the different experience of others.